# Problems with the dymola runtime ln function

Tags: modelica

I was writing a dynamic model recently, but I ran into some problems that I couldn't solve.
The following is part of the code, the function I want to implement is that when `Tb2` is less than the saturation temperature `Tbaohe`, the logarithmic average temperature difference `T1` is used to solve, and when `Tb2` is equal to the saturation temperature, continue to use the arithmetic average temperature difference `T2` on the basis of the above solution results to continue the solution, where `Tc1` is equal to `Tbaohe`.

```
  Kc*Ac*T3 = (Wnjs + Gna)*(hc1 - hb2);
  T1 = ((Te1 - Tbaohe) - (Tc1 - Tb2))/(ln((Te1 - Tbaohe)/(Tc1 - Tb2)));
  T2 = (Te1 + Tbaohe)/2 - (Tc1 + Tb2)/2;
  if Tb2 < Tbaohe then
    T3 = T1;
  else
    T3 = T2;
  end if;
```

But when I solve, I get the following error. Apparently there is a problem with the `ln` function here, it seems that when `Tb2` is infinitely close to the saturation temperature `Tbaohe`, the run stops automatically, I can't fix this.

```
Error: The following error was detected at time: 10.86044238659505

Model error - division by zero: (Te1-Tbaohe) / (Tc1-Tb2) = (104.936) / (0)

First evaluation failed for non-linear solver.

First evaluation failed for non-linear solver.
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two temperatures become close, you are dividing by zero.  Tb2 should not become larger than Tc1, otherwise you would get a negative value for the ln function. You could use max(1e-4, (Tc1 - Tb2)) instead of (Tc1 - Tb2). If Tb2 is intended to become larger than Tc1, than there might be an error in your equation. The complete source code would be helpful to identify variables and parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I think the fundamental issue here is that your write equations, not assignment statements or macros. So both T1 and T2 are always "active", not just in alternating branches of your if statement. Your model says the equations for T1 and T2 are always satisfied.

Comment: @ Dag B  I can understand what you mean, but how do I make changes?

Comment: @white I would simply take the expressions definiting T1 and T2 and substitute them in the if-statement. Just eliminate T1 and T2.